# Minimap extension error when load custom model by SceneBuilder in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I try to load the external geometry following this [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer). The model already loaded successfully but when i open the BimWalk and it appears an error

> "Cannot read property 'getRootNode' of null"

Is there any solution to fix this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you clarify it is about loading minimap extension or switch to BIMWalk , or load them both? I tried the live demo of that blog. It looks not such error when loading these extensions. https://codepen.io/coldwood/pen/yLaKRoN . Could you also update the code to demo how to reproduce the error at your side?

Comment: Hi Xiaodong Liang, Can you please try to load the AEC data from the model. I think i get this problem when I run `document.downloadAecModelData()`  on DocumentLoadSuccess callback . The error is  `Cannot read property 'getAecModelData' of null` and it loop infinite

Comment: I also need to load AEC data to display minimap when I'm in the Bimwalk mode . Is there any solution to fix this problem while still using AEC data and add a new custom model at the same time ?

Comment: Hi Trung, I think the live demo of that blog packages something that caused the method is not accessible. If you use a native test skeleton such as https://oss-manager.autodesk.io , AEC data works well with this model.  https://ibb.co/BgnQc52

Comment: if you still have the problem, could you send us the test model, code and steps to forge.help@autodesk.com?

Comment: Thanks Liang, I'll check it.